# multiline regex pattern that stops at empty line

Tags: regex

I am looking for a regex pattern that starts with a specific string on the first line, contains one of a set of strings on the following line, and ends with an empty line. For example, it must start with `- hello: world`; it must contain a line with `fruit: apple` or `fruit: banana`, and it must end with an empty lines. So the pattern would match the first two blocks here, but not the third:

```
- hello: world
  fruit: apple
  foo: bar
  key: value

- hello: world
  fruit: banana
  message: hi

- hello: world
  fruit: orange
  message: hi
```

This is what I have so far:

```
/- hello: world\s*fruit: (apple|banana)/g
```

What I'm looking for is the rest that will stop at the empty line.

Comment: Trying to parse YAML with a regex? Why not use a parsed that is build for that?

Comment: What is your desired output? Those 2 objects?

Comment: Try it like this `- hello: world\n[^\S\n]*fruit: (apple|banana)(?:\n[^\S\n]*\S.*)*` https://regex101.com/r/01cnmf/1

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a Regex, use a parsed like [yq](/questions/tagged/yq) that is build for parsing YAML.

---

So if the input file looks something like:

```yaml
myData:
  - hello: world
    fruit: apple
    foo: bar
    key: value
  - hello: world
    fruit: banana
    message: hi
  - hello: world
    fruit: orange
    message: hi
```

Use an [yq](/questions/tagged/yq) filter to filter the output where the following conditions are `true`

- `.hello == "world"`
- `.fruit == "apple" or .fruit == "banana"`:

```
yq e '.myData | map(select(.hello == "world" and (.fruit == "apple" or .fruit == "banana")))' /path/to/input/file
```

Output:

```yaml
- hello: world
  fruit: apple
  foo: bar
  key: value
- hello: world
  fruit: banana
  message: hi
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `\s*` matches optional whitespace characters which *might* also match newline.

The pattern `world\s*fruit` that you are using could also match `worldfruit` or `world  fruit`

If there should be a newline in between, and not matching empty lines:

```
- hello: world\n[^\S\n]*fruit: (?:apple|banana)\b(?:\n[^\S\n]*\S.*)*
```

**Explanation**

- `- hello: world\n` Match literally followed by a newline
- `[^\S\n]*fruit:`   Match optional spaces followed by `fruit:`
- `(?:apple|banana)\b` Match either  `apple` or  `banana` followed by a word boundary
- `(?:` Non capture group to repeat as a whole part

  - `\n[^\S\n]*\S.*` Match a newline, optional spaces and a non white space character followed by the rest of the line
- `)*` Close the non capture group and optionally repeat it to match all lines

See a [regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/2pm7GO/1).